# Rewrite MySQL Trigger to Postgres

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

guys!

I have a trigger in MySQL database:

```
CREATE DEFINER="root"@"127.0.0.1" TRIGGER `tai_actions_for_active_count` AFTER INSERT ON `actions` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE l_isnn TINYTEXT;
  IF NEW.action_type IN ('CREATION', 'VERIFICATION', 'CLOSE') THEN

    SET l_isnn = IF(NEW.isnn is NULL, '*', NEW.isnn);
    IF NOT NEW.action_type = 'CLOSE' THEN
      INSERT INTO subscriptions.`statistics_active_count`(`service_id`, `operator_id`, `isnn`, `active_count`)
        VALUES (NEW.service_id, NEW.operator_id, l_isnn, 1)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE active_count = active_count + 1;
    ELSE
      SET @tai_actions_for_active_count = -1;
      UPDATE subscriptions.`statistics_active_count` SET active_count = @tai_actions_for_active_count := active_count - 1
        WHERE `service_id` = NEW.service_id AND `operator_id` = NEW.operator_id AND `isnn` = l_isnn;
      IF @tai_actions_for_active_count = 0 THEN DELETE FROM subscriptions.`statistics_active_count` WHERE `active_count` = 0; END IF;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END
```

So I need to rewrite it to make it works in Postgres database. As there's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` I'm using Postgres version 9.5 with `UPSERT` `(ON CONFLICT (KEY) DO UPDATE)`.

So I poorly know SQL language can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? There's the Postgres PL code:

```
  DECLARE
    l_isnn TEXT;
    tai_actions_for_active_count INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.action_type IN ('CREATION', 'VERIFICATION', 'CLOSE') THEN
        IF NEW.isnn is NULL THEN
            l_isnn := '*';
        ELSE
            l_isnn := NEW.isnn;
        END IF;
        IF NOT NEW.action_type = 'CLOSE' THEN
            INSERT INTO "subscriptions.statistics_active_count"(service_id, operator_id, isnn, active_count)
                VALUES (NEW.service_id, NEW.operator_id, l_isnn, 1)
                ON CONFLICT(active_count) DO UPDATE SET active_count = active_count + 1;
        ELSE
            tai_actions_for_active_count := -1;
            UPDATE "subscriptions.statistics_active_count" SET active_count = active_count - 1
        -- (tai_actions_for_active_count := active_count - 1)
                WHERE service_id = NEW.service_id AND operator_id = NEW.operator_id AND isnn = l_isnn;
            UPDATE "subscriptions.statistics_active_count" SET tai_actions_for_active_count = active_count
                WHERE service_id = NEW.service_id AND operator_id = NEW.operator_id AND isnn = l_isnn;
            IF tai_actions_for_active_count = 0 THEN DELETE FROM "subscriptions.statistics_active_count" WHERE active_count = 0; END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
  END;
```

As I want to test this trigger I'm getting an error -- `relation "subscriptions.statistics_active_count" does not exist`

Can you help me with that code?

Comment: You got that error because statistics_active_count probably does not exist. I mean, do to you have a table named subscriptions.statistics_active_count? Or you have a table named statistics_active_count in subscriptions schema? If table and schema are lower case, just remove quoting and it will run.

Comment: @user_0, I have statistics_active_count table in subscriptions database. I tried to remove quotes now but it's still this error.

Comment: If subscription is current database, just remove it from syntax. If not, please add some information about schemas, db, foreigndatawrappers involved.

Comment: I've removed `subscription` and now I have another error :) It says `column reference "active_count" is ambiguous` at  `(..NFLICT(active_count) DO UPDATE SET active_count = active_cou...)`. As I understand I need to select "active_count" somehow from database?

Comment: Use table prefixes for columns.

Comment: @user_0, now I've got `ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification`. What should I do now?

Comment: To have more support I think it will be useful to add involved tables' definitions to your post. So a user can recreate them and rewrite the trigger.

Comment: Good on you for attempting it, not just saying "how do I convert this trigger" and expecting someone else to do it. I think we need to see the definitions of the tables, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've got the solution. I guess :)

```
BEGIN
   IF NEW.action_type IN ('CREATION', 'VERIFICATION', 'CLOSE') THEN
      IF NEW.isnn IS NULL THEN
         l_isnn := '*';
      ELSE
         l_isnn := NEW.isnn;
      END IF;
      IF NOT NEW.action_type = 'CLOSE' THEN
         BEGIN
            INSERT INTO subscriptions.statistics_active_count (service_id, operator_id, isnn, active_count)
            VALUES (NEW.service_id, NEW.operator_id, l_isnn, 1);
         EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
            UPDATE subscriptions.statistics_active_count  SET active_count = active_count + 1
            WHERE service_id = NEW.service_id and operator_id=NEW.operator_id;
         END;
      ELSE
         tai_actions_for_active_count := -1;
         WITH upd AS
         (UPDATE subscriptions.statistics_active_count
         SET active_count = active_count - 1
         WHERE service_id = NEW.service_id AND operator_id = NEW.operator_id AND isnn = l_isnn;
         RETURNING active_count)
         SELECT *
         FROM upd INTO tai_actions_for_active_count;
         IF tai_actions_for_active_count = 0 THEN
            DELETE FROM public.statistics_active_count
            WHERE active_count = 0;
         END IF;
      END IF;
   END IF;
END;
```